# Running remote JBoss in debug mode, Bootup Time Issue

Tags: debugging, jboss, timeout, remote-debugging

I am trying to run remote jboss in debug mode to debug my application and i have set

`set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y %JAVA_OPTS%`

in `run.bat` file, and am trying to start the jboss server using `ant jboss.start` but it is taking some time and then timing out, am not sure why this is happening, is there a way out?

Also as jboss is timing out, I would like to increase bootup time for the server, how can i do it from the command line?

Side note, server.log file does not show any messages which jboss is trying to bootup in debug mode (not sure if this would help but thought so sharing this info.)

Any clue or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set:

```
suspend=n
```

in debugger [startup settings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html).

> suspend - True if the target VM is to be suspended immediately before the main class is loaded; false otherwise.

Your JBoss waits infinitely for debugger connection, this is useful when you want to troubleshoot startup issues, otherwise do not suspend your VM and let the debugger be connected any time you want.

Comment: Yes, in place where you have `suspend=y` change it to `suspend=n`. That's it. Note that the only thing JBoss outputs is "*Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787*" on the terminal, it didn't even reached the `main` class.

Comment: it it still taking that long, how to increase timeout?

Comment: Can you disable the debugger completely? Can you see some logs rolling by during startup or still nothing? If the VM is no longer suspended and waiting for debugger connection you might have some other issues.

Comment: I have stopped the debugger and I do see the logs rolling during startup, if i enable the debugger then jboss does not start and has bootup time to infinity, not sure what exactly is happening in here?

Comment: what are you referring to debugger connection in here?

Comment: First question: if you disable the debugger completely can you start the server fine without any timeouts? If so, debugger is the problem. Now: `suspend=y` causes JVM (not even JBoss) to wait for debugger connections infinitely on 8787 TCP port. You have to connect to the JVM using Eclipse remote debugging session or something similar to move forward. If you don't do this the JVM will just sit there waiting. However if you set `suspend=n` the server will still accept debugger connections but in background, not suspending the startup process.

Comment: Yes, if debugger is disabled then i can start my application fine. Ok now here is the thing, my applicaiton runs at `localhost:10080` and in my `run.bat` file port number is `8787` and in my eclipse debug configuration also it is set to `8787` am not sure but that could cause the issue?

Comment: 10080 is your HTTP port you use to access your application via web browser. 8787 is a debugger port, accessed by Eclipse debugger. They are fine as long as they are not the same ;-). Can you try again running the server with `server=n,suspend=n`? It shouldn't really make any difference as compared to no debugger configuration.

Comment: It ran finally, all i had to do was to remove all `java.exe` process and re-start the server and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was frustated to get jboss started in debug mode through command line
Finally following seemed to work

1.Below should be the last line in /bin/run.conf.bat

rem # Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging

set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%

If there is anything below this, delete it.

2.Also when you are running jboss from command prompt please check whether -Xdebug is at the start of JAVA_OPTS.
Then it should display following message
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787

3.In eclipse use 127.0.0.1 instaed of localhost.
I don't know the reason behind it...but when I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 it worked
(Make sure you replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 at 2 locations 1.Eclipse remote debug and 2.URL while running your application in browser)
Also check project name.
Sometimes we need to change the port number.

I never had such issues with tomcat.